# Use Devise::TokenGenerator inside a model that is not devise model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails app with devise configured, but I also have a model with simple `has_secure_password` authentication, and I wish to provide password recover functionality using `Devise.token_generator` to generate, encrypt and check the forgot password token, but I get `unitialized constant SimpleAuthModel::Devise` constantly.

Is it possible to use it? `require 'devise'` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `SecureRandom.hex(n)` and it works properly.